# Does a piezoelectric organic substance exist?

Tags: muscles

that contracts rapidly, in 10 seconds or less, by .5mm or more, when bombarded by electrons as from a cathode ray tube? or expands? could either be living tissue or dead organic matter.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit specific, but piezoelectric organic substances do exist. There was a paper in nature that researchers at Berkeley published.

Please see the following journal article:
http://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v7/n6/full/nnano.2012.69.html#affil-auth

Also see the following public article:
http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/129389-berkeley-scientists-turn-harmless-virus-into-piezoelectric-generator

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it would contract by the amount that you are after, but bone (which has both organic and inorganic components) is piezoelectric.

For an overview, see http://silver.neep.wisc.edu/~lakes/BoneElectr.html.

> They suggest that two different mechanisms are responsible for these effects: classical piezoelectricity due to the molecular asymmetry of collagen in dry bone, and fluid flow effects, possibly streaming potentials in wet bone.